# Powershell v2 - Installing Printer

Tags: powershell, printers

I'm trying to automate printer installation on windows 7 x64, by using Powershell script. So far I have a script that successfully creates TCP/IP port but gives me an error - **The arguments are invalid**, when it executes printer installation part of the code. Any ideas on how to fix the problem and successfully install a printer through the Powershell? The code is as follows:

```
$hostAddress = "172.16.2.24" 
$portNumber = "9100"  
$computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME 

$wmi= [wmiclass]"\\$computer\root\cimv2:win32_tcpipPrinterPort" 
#$wmi.psbase.scope.options.enablePrivileges = $true 
$newPort = $wmi.createInstance() 

$newPort.hostAddress = $hostAddress 
$newPort.name = "IP_" + $hostAddress 
$newPort.portNumber = $portNumber 
$newPort.SNMPEnabled = $false 
$newPort.Protocol = 1 
$newPort.put()

CMD.EXE /C "printui.exe /if /b "Test Printer" /f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ftp\Prdrivers\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-5.7.0.16448\hpbuio100l.inf /r "IP_172.16.2.24" /m "HP Laser Jet P3015""
```

Question Update: This is the working CMD code, so how do I incorporate it into the Powershell code above ?

```
printui.exe /if /b "HP Universal Printing PCL 6" /f "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ftp\Prdrivers\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-5.7.0.16448\hpbuio100l.inf" /u /r "IP_172.16.2.24" /m "HP Universal Printing PCL 6"
```

Comment: Is this a networked print queue?

Comment: I think is a quote issue. Could you try this: `cmd.exe /c printui.exe /if /b "Test Printer" /f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ftp\Prdrivers\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-5.7.0.16448\hpbuio100l.inf /r "IP_172.16.2.24" /m "HP Laser Jet P3015"`

Comment: @MDMoore313 No, it's not a print queue. It's a local IP printer installation.

Comment: @C.B. I have updated my question, please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To embed double-quotes within a double-quoted string you need to escape them.  Since you are not using variables, it is easier to use a single quoted string e.g.:

```
CMD.EXE /C 'printui.exe /if /b "Test Printer" /f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ftp\Prdrivers\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-5.7.0.16448\hpbuio100l.inf /r "IP_172.16.2.24" /m "HP Laser Jet P3015"'
```

If you ever need to use PowerShell variables inside this string, then you will need to switch back to double quotes and escape the necessary DQ characters e.g:

```
CMD.EXE /C "printui.exe /if /b `"$PrinterName`" /f C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ftp\Prdrivers\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-5.7.0.16448\hpbuio100l.inf /r `"IP_172.16.2.24`" /m `"HP Laser Jet P3015`""
```

Comment: Thanks! I have it up and running now.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but im not sure why you are calling CMD /C @PARAMS.  I am just calling the printui.exe directly and it is working, and I only double quote the Args

```
# Printer Info, I keep this in an SQL DB, and return these values with a query:
$printerID = "<PrinterNameOrID>"
$printerIP = "<PrinterIP>"
$printerPort = "IP_$printerIP"
$printerModel = "<PrinterModelFromINF>"
$driverINFPath = "<UNCPathToDriverINF>"

# Build a new Local TCP Printer Port, naming it with values unique to the Printer ID:
$newPort = ([wmiclass]"Win32_TcpIpPrinterPort").CreateInstance()
$newPort.HostAddress = $printerIP
$newPort.Name = $printerPort
$newPort.PortNumber = "9100"
$newPort.Protocol = 1
$newPort.Put()

# Add the printer
printui.exe /if /b "$printerID" /f "$driverINFPath" /u /r "$printerPort" /m "$printerModel"
```

Comment: Actually, should probably Splat the PrinterInfo.

Comment: best answer, OP wants powershell

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered but you could borrow the code I have in this Excel Workbook (there is a link in the article).  I realize it uses VBS but these are built in scripts in Windows and cutting / pasting into Excel has saved me many times and I've installed thousands of printers this way

[best-tool-for-printer-creation-excel-vs-print-management-console](http://www.ballisticecho.com/resources/best-tool-for-printer-creation-excel-vs-print-management-console)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
runas /user:Contoso.com\user1 "printui.exe /if /b \"Test Printer\" /f \"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ftp\Prdrivers\HP Universal Print Driver\pcl6-x64-5.7.0.16448\hpbuio100l.inf\" /r \"IP_172.16.2.24\" /m \"HP Laser Jet P3015\""
```